# Sharepoint publishing site pages and navigation

Tags: sharepoint, navigation

When I create pages in a publishing site the pages are automatically added to the navigation.

What if I dont want certain pages to show on the navigation, how can I do that automatically/conditionally?

Comment: It's unclear whether you are looking for a programmatic solution here. If you're just interested in configuration, ask on http://superuser.com

Comment: Cheers Alex, programmatic actually, I should have made that clearer. I have found a possible solution using audiences, would appreciate your thoughts on whether this is the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [blog post from Ton Stegeman](http://www.tonstegeman.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=76) should tell you everything you need to know. Look at [PublishingWeb.ExcludeFromNavigation()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishingweb.excludefromnavigation.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Remove them from the navigation using site settings?